# how can i compare two groups of data?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, method-comparison

I asked a question here [how can i see if my data are coming from two different population?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230255/how-can-i-see-if-my-data-are-coming-from-two-different-population) and seems like I cannot correctly communicate and the person who is writing to me is making me confused.

So I try to explain what I want , if you know any method, please just tell me the method, I will try to do it myself.

I have two groups 
**Group A** with **n** number of **samples** 
**Group B** with **m** number of **samples**

The measurements have replicate

I want to see if the Group A is different from Group B.
for example by the mean, or whatever else which makes statistically different or not different.

Is there someone who can really guide me what to do?
Many thanks
Nik

Answer (score 1):

From reading your previous post, I see that you have two groups with 15 subjects, each with multiple observations (3 each). Each subject appears in each group, except subject 15 who has 0 observation in group 1.

So, basically, you have a paired design. A way to test whether Group 1 and Group 2 are different is by using a paired wilcoxon signed rank sum test. In R, this can be done using the following code:

```
df<- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                              1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                              1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                              1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                              2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                              2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Subject = c(1L, 
                                                                                                   1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
                                                                                                   6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
                                                                                                   11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                   2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
                                                                                                   7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
                                                                                                   12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L), 
                    Value = c(29.89577946, 29.51885854, 29.77429604, 33.20695108, 
                              32.09027292, 31.90909894, 30.88358173, 30.67547731, 30.82494595, 
                              31.70128247, 31.57217504, 31.61359752, 30.51371055, 30.42241945, 
                              30.44913954, 26.90850496, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28.94047335, 29.27188604, 
                              29.78511206, 28.18475423, 27.54266717, 26.99873401, 29.26941344, 
                              28.50457189, 28.78050443, 31.39038527, 31.19237052, 30.74053275, 
                              28.68618888, 28.42109545, 28.58222544, 28.99337177, 29.31797, 
                              28.4541501, 28.18475423, 27.54266717, 26.99873401, 28.07576794, 
                              28.96344894, 28.48358437, 27.02527663, 27.1308483, 26.96091103, 
                              27.04019758, 27.51900858, 28.14559621, 26.83569136, 26.90724462, 
                              26.82675, 0, 0, 0, 27.62449786, 26.82335228, 26.66925534, 
                              0, 25.81254792, 26.61666776, 26.12545858, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                              28.84580419, 29.11003424, 29.24723895, 28.72919768, 29.70673437, 
                              29.31274377, 30.73133587, 30.44805655, 30.61561583, 27.06896964, 
                              27.04249553, 27.15990629, 31.54738209, 31.51643714, 31.8055509, 
                              31.291867, 31.89146186, 31.65812735)), .Names = c("Group", 
                                                                                "Subject", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                         -87L))



df$Value[df$Value == 0] <- NA

df[is.na(df$Value),] ## missing data

table(df$Group, df$Subject) ## check to see if all groups have equal obs


## perform wilcoxon signed rank sum test 
wilcox.test(formula = Value ~ Group, data = df[!df$Subject == 15,]) ## omit the 15th patient

Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  Value by Group
W = 900, p-value = 0.0006732
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(x = c(29.89577946, 29.51885854, 29.77429604,  :
                               cannot compute exact p-value with ties

## we can reject the null hypothesis that both groups are equal
```

From the R documentation,

> If exact p-values are available, an exact confidence interval is obtained by the algorithm described in Bauer (1972), and the Hodges-Lehmann estimator is employed. Otherwise, the returned confidence interval and point estimate are based on normal approximations. These are continuity-corrected for the interval but not the estimate (as the correction depends on the alternative).

Comment: From the previous thread it seems possible that the zeros are really missings, so watch out.

Comment: @Johnnyboycurtis you discard the sample 15 ? means both group should have equal sample size? Yes zero means missing , I have already normalised the data but i don't know if I can assume that they are normally distributed

Comment: @Nick Cox I don't know how to thank you for your valuable comment !!!! Yes this is true, the zeros are missing values. If you have a solution (for example somehow filling up the missing values, etc, my ears are all yours

Comment: @NikBernou, please see the updates. I've updated the code so that 0s are treated as missing values. I would not advice trying to impute the missing data as this will cause further issues. Keep the analysis simple and straightforward. Also, don't bother using a t-test, keep with Wilcoxon test as it is more robust and requires less assumptions about the data. If this answer is satisfactory, please up vote it and check your question off as answered.

Comment: @Johnnyboycurtis I do like your answer but you remove one of the sample, you don't explain why Wilcoxon test and why not another one, you rejected the hypothesis that they are equal but is it possible to give an explanation that why ? is it based on mean of the group, is it because of standard deviation ? did you check the linearity of the data?

Comment: I think if you read his original post the OP in fact has independent groups.

Answer (score 1):

When thinking about a statistical problem, you should ask yourself what experiment you have.

You have two groups, with different sample size. You can calculate arithmetic mean over all your replicates. You will be able to use the means for comparison.

1:) Check if you can assume normality. Because your data is simple, you can just do a simple QQ plot or histogram.

2:) If you can assume normality, you should use paired t-test.

3:) If you can't assume normality, you should Wilcox signed-rank test

Comment: can you give me an example based on my data ?

Answer (score 0):

For comparing means of populations with different samples, the standard practice is applying a two-sample location test. Depending on the size of your data, you could implement either a t-test or a z-test (t-test is recommended for smaller sample sizes).

In any case, since you want to find out if the groups are *different*, a two-sided test would be ideal for the purpose. Since the data has different sizes, it is generally accepted that a Welch's test is the best way of performing such comparison. The Welch's test assumes unequal variances, an assumption you could test yourself. In case you have reasons to believe that the variances are equal instead, it is recommended that you use a *paired* t-test.

In R, assuming your data is stored un vectors `x` and `y`

```
#Welch's t-test
t.test(x,y)

#paired sample test
t.test(x,y, paired = TRUE) 

#test for equality of variances
var.test(x,y)
```

Comment: Welch's test assume that I have equal variance over the data, I don't know if it holds, I also don't know how to perform the t.test two sides on this data, x should be value from one group and y should be value from the other group?

Comment: @NikBernou to test if the variance is equal, use the last line of code `var.test(x,y)`. If the resulting p-value of the test is > 0.05 (or whatever significance value), it means that the variances can be assumed to be equal (their ration is not much far from 1). If that's the case, then simply use `t.test(x,y)`.

Comment: Wiki: "In statistics, Welch's t-test, or unequal variances t-test, is a two-sample location test which is used to test the hypothesis that two populations have equal means. "

Comment: Notes on Welch's test: [link](http://statistics.berkeley.edu/computing/r-t-tests)

Comment: do the QQ plot of my data, you see is really different

Comment: @Nik Why do you think that Welch's test assumes equal variance?

Comment: Welch test doesn't assume equal variance, and in fact that's what it's designed for.